# Changing the name of a html class with for loop variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several of html class's incrementing up in class name such as:

```
<div class="chicken1">
    <b></b>
</div>
<div class="chicken2">
    <b></b>
</div>
<div class="chicken3">
    <b></b>
</div>
```

I'm trying to write a for loop which will loop through these class names, adding the index to the end each class name and then calling a function in 2s delays.

```
for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myFunction(".chicken" + i + " b");
    }, 2000 * i);
}
```

However this isn't working.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jw0130uw/1/)

Comment: 1. where is your myFunction. 2. You are passing a string rather than a dom

Comment: What's the expected outcome?

Comment: myfunction is a function above the code.... I didn't provide it in order to simplify the question.

Comment: I'm curious to know *why* do you want to do that ? This has all symptoms of a bad pattern. @ramr please add this function for us to see what's wrong in your code, because currently the only thing we get when running your code is `myFunction is not a function` so I doesn't help.

Comment: Here i'll update the code with a jsfiddle one moment

Comment: I'm trying to simplify  my code with a for loop @jack http://jsfiddle.net/jw0130uw/1/

Comment: @ramr I've updated your fiddle with a few JS tricks, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/3gqfh35t/1/. The code is not working at the moment but that's not my point here (hope you learn some tricks). Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually that of `setTimeout()` called within a loop; to do this properly you have to close over the loop variable:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
    setTimeout((function(i) {
        return function() {
            myFunction(".chicken" + i + " i");
        };
    })(i), i * 2000);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jw0130uw/2/)

It uses a function that gets called immediately, passing the value of `i`; this value is retained until the `setTimeout()` is fired.

Answer (score 0):

are you using jquery? try

```
for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
    myFunction($(".chicken" + i + " b"));
}
```

in jquery, to select elements,class etc. we need `$("<selector here>");`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="chicken1">
    <b></b>
</div>
<div class="chicken2">
    <b></b>
</div>
<div class="chicken3">
    <b></b>
</div>


<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
            $(".chicken"+i+" b").html("Hey " + i);
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```